# form submit to iframe: request payload not including file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file input field like this:

```
   <input type="file" validate="" data-val-msg="" id="file-img" name="file-img">
```

without a form wrapped around it.

In javascript, I'm catching the `onchange` to wrap a form around it and make it post to a hidden iframe to achieve an ajax-alike behaviour:

```
element.bind('change',function(e){
   var form = $('<form target="upload_frame" method="post"   action="'+attrs['uploadAction']+'">')
   .attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data")
   .attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    element.wrap(form);

   form.on('submit',function(e){
      var iframe = $('<iframe>', {
         id: 'upload_frame',
         name: 'upload_frame'
       }).on('load',function(){
          // do stuff.
       }).appendTo(document.body);
   });
   form.trigger('submit');
});
```

The ajax call itself is working, but when I look in chrome's debugger > network tab, I see that the file isn't sent. I only see:

```
Request payload: ------WebKitFormBoundary5MjUXZBbAeFAEprp--
```

What I should see is something like this:

```
Request payload: ------WebKitFormBoundary5MjUXZBbAeFAEprp--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-img"; filename="afile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Does anyone see what is going wrong?
Is jquery/javascript restricting me to create a form on the fly?